# How to Alter table using JOOQ?

Tags: java, sql, jooq

Previously I was working with statement but I need to convert it with JOOQ

```
  Statement dboSt = null; 

dboSt = dboConn.createStatement();
```

I need to know how to change my below lines in JOOQ.

```
dboSt.executeUpdate("alter login \"" + UserId + "\" with password='" + NewPassword + "'");

dboSt.executeUpdate("alter login \"" + UserId + "\" with password='" + NewPassword + "' old_password='" + OldPassword
                                + "'");
```

Is there any solution to convert it?

Answer (score 0):

jOOQ doesn't support typesafe DDL (yet). It's been on the roadmap for a while: [#883](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/883)

In the mean time, you can execute plain SQL statements using jOOQ directly, as such:

```java
DSLContext ctx = DSL.using(configuration);

// As before, manually inlining arguments:
ctx.execute("alter login \""+UserId+"\" with password='"+NewPassword+"'");

// Better, letting jOOQ do the string escaping for you, preventing
// syntax errors and SQL injection vulnerabilities:
ctx.execute("alter login {0} with password = {1}",
    DSL.name(UserId),       // org.jooq.Name is rendered with quotes in most DBs
    DSL.inline(NewPassword) // org.jooq.Param is inlined as a (string) literal
);
```

Comment: how to convert below code:
dboSt.executeUpdate("alter login \"" + UserId + "\" with password='" + NewPassword + "' old_password='" + OldPassword
                                + "'");

Comment: @psisodia: Getting that answer is only a small step from my existing answer. You can do some of the thinking yourself :-)